# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy, tomcat6, httpbuilder

When I run my grails application locally under Tomcat, I get no errors. When I deploy my WAR on my remote web server, I get this exception when I try to make an AJAX request that uses HTTPBuilder.

How could this be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running your application is an IDE like STS? if so maybe the Jars for HTTPBuilder are in your build/run path but are not in your lib directory for the Grails app OR not listed as a "Production" Dependency.

Comment: ...yeah. They were on my path but not in the WAR. Sometimes I think the notion of the Java classpath obfuscates visibility.

Comment: Have to agree. Glad I could help.